# ¿Cómo validar los valores dentro del formulario?

Tags: javascript, html, css, formularios, validación

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en *HTML*, *CSS* y *JavaScript* para mejorar la insulina. Me encuentro con la siguiente problemática, quiero validar las preguntas:

1. ¿Cuáles son las calorías consumidas?

   Que los valores estén entre 133 y 2400.
2. ¿Cuál es la cantidad de insulina recomendada por su médico?

   Que esté entre 5 y 70.

En caso de no estar dentro de estos parámetros el mensaje puede ser el que quieran.

```js
var usuario = prompt("¿Cuáles son las calorías consumidas?");
var cal = prompt("¿Cuál es la cantidad de insulina recomendada por su médico?");
var peso = parseInt(usuario);
var planeta = prompt(
  "Oprime del 1 al 10, si estás seguro, caso contrario Cancelar \n La cantidad de calorías ingeridas es de: " +
 usuario +
 " y la cantidad de insulina recomendada por su médico es de: " +
 cal
);
var g_calorias = 1.8;
var g_masa = 2.7;
var peso_final;
if (peso >= 105) {
  if (planeta >= 1 && planeta < 11) {
 peso_final = peso + cal / g_calorias - 100;
 peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
 document.write(
   "\n\n La cantidad de insulina a ingerir es <strong> " +
  peso_final +
  " Ml </strong>"
 );
  } else if (planeta == 34) {
 peso_final = peso * g_jupiter / g_calorias;
 peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
 document.write(
   " Tu peso en Júpiter es <strong> " + peso_final + " kilos</strong>."
 );
  } else {
 document.write("No estás siendo muy honesto.");
  }
  peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
} else {
  document.write(
 "La cantidad de calorías ingresadas no constan como una comida."
  );
}
```

Comment: Por favor, comparte el código completo que implica el desarrollo con el que estás pidiendo a la comunidad que te ayude. En este caso entiendo que tienes un html con inputs o un form...

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que el mensaje puede ser el que quieran.?